How to bulk update Stripe subscription prices through the API for a WordPress site that uses MemberPress?
I have a WordPress site with the MemberPress plugin, and my subscriptions are connected to Stripe for payments. Unfortunately, MemberPress does not have a built-in option to bulk update subscription prices, and Stripe's dashboard doesn't seem to provide a native way to do this either.
I need to update approximately 5,000 active subscriptions to a new price in Stripe. I’ve written a PHP script that successfully worked in Stripe’s test mode, but I’m unsure about the following:

Can my script handle updating 5,000 subscriptions through WordPress and PHP on a single page execution? What are the risks and potential issues with server performance or timeouts?
Is it safe and appropriate to manually update membership prices in WordPress/MemberPress to reflect the new prices from Stripe, or is there a better way to keep both platforms in sync?

Could you take a look at my code and provide any feedback or suggestions? Your help would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the script with comments:
<?php
/*
This script is designed to update all Stripe subscriptions tied to a **specific price ID**.
It retrieves all subscriptions that are linked to an old price and updates them to a new price,
but only if both prices belong to the same product.
The update process is triggered by a URL parameter in the WordPress admin interface.

Steps:
1. Retrieve all subscriptions associated with the old price ID.
2. Verify that the old and new prices belong to the same product.
3. If they do, update those subscriptions to the new price.
4. Trigger the update via a URL parameter in the admin area.

*/

// Function to get the product ID for a specific price ID
function get_product_id_for_price($price_id, $api_key) {
    // Prepare cURL request to retrieve the price details
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/prices/$price_id");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":");

    // Execute the cURL request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Decode the response to get the price details
    $price_details = json_decode($response, true);

    // Return the product ID if the price exists, otherwise return null
    return isset($price_details['product']) ? $price_details['product'] : null;
}

// Function to get all subscriptions for a specific price ID
// This retrieves all subscriptions tied to a given price, supporting pagination if needed.
function get_all_subscriptions_for_price($price_id, $api_key) {
    $subscriptions = [];
    $has_more = true;
    $starting_after = null;

    // Loop through all pages of subscriptions until all are retrieved
    while ($has_more) {
        // Build the request URL, and include pagination if necessary
        $ch = curl_init();
        $url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions?price=$price_id&limit=100";

        if ($starting_after) {
            $url .= "&starting_after=$starting_after";
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":");

        // Execute the API request and store the result
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode the JSON response into an array
        $result = json_decode($response, true);

        // If subscriptions are found, merge them with the existing list
        if (isset($result['data'])) {
            $subscriptions = array_merge($subscriptions, $result['data']);
            $has_more = $result['has_more'];
            $starting_after = end($result['data'])['id'];
        } else {
            // No more pages of subscriptions
            $has_more = false;
        }
    }

    return $subscriptions;
}

// Function to update all retrieved subscriptions to a new price
// This function takes an array of subscriptions and updates them to a new price ID.
function update_subscriptions_with_new_price($subscriptions, $new_price_id, $api_key) {
    foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
        $subscription_id = $subscription['id'];
        $subscription_item_id = $subscription['items']['data'][0]['id'];

        // Prepare cURL request to update the subscription with the new price
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/$subscription_id");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key . ":");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
            'items[0][id]' => $subscription_item_id,
            'items[0][price]' => $new_price_id,
        ]));

        // Execute the cURL request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode the response and check for any errors
        $update_result = json_decode($response, true);
        if (isset($update_result['error'])) {
            echo "Error updating subscription ID $subscription_id: " . $update_result['error']['message'];
        } else {
            echo "Subscription ID $subscription_id updated successfully.\n";
        }
    }
}

// Function to update subscriptions for a specific price ID
// This retrieves all subscriptions linked to the old price and updates them to a new price if both prices belong to the same product.
function update_specific_subscriptions_for_price($product_id, $old_price_id, $new_price_id) {
    // Your Stripe secret API key to authenticate API requests
    $api_key = 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxx';  // Stripe secret key

    // Step 1: Get the product IDs for the old and new prices
    $old_price_product_id = get_product_id_for_price($old_price_id, $api_key);
    $new_price_product_id = get_product_id_for_price($new_price_id, $api_key);

    // Step 2: Check if both prices belong to the specified product
    if ($old_price_product_id === $product_id && $new_price_product_id === $product_id) {
        echo "Both prices belong to the specified product. Proceeding with subscription updates.\n";

        // Step 3: Get all subscriptions tied to the old price ID
        $subscriptions = get_all_subscriptions_for_price($old_price_id, $api_key);

        // Step 4: If there are subscriptions, update them to the new price ID
        if (!empty($subscriptions)) {
            update_subscriptions_with_new_price($subscriptions, $new_price_id, $api_key);
        } else {
            echo "No subscriptions found for Price ID: $old_price_id\n";
        }
    } else {
        // Prices do not belong to the same product or specified product, do not proceed
        echo "Error: One or both of the price IDs do not belong to the specified product. No updates will be made.\n";
    }
}

// Example usage: Admin function to trigger subscription updates via a URL parameter
add_action('admin_init', function() {
    // The Product ID that both prices must belong to
    $product_id = 'prod_xxxxxxxxx';  // The actual product ID

    // The old Price ID that you want to update
    $old_price_id = 'price_xxxxxxxxx';    // The actual old price ID from Stripe

    // The new Price ID to which subscriptions should be updated
    $new_price_id = 'price_xxxxxxxxxx';    // The new price ID
    
    

    // Check if the update process is triggered by the URL parameter
    if (isset($_GET['trigger_subscription_update']) && $_GET['trigger_subscription_update'] === 'true') {
        // Run the function to update subscriptions tied to the old price ID
        update_specific_subscriptions_for_price($product_id, $old_price_id, $new_price_id);
    }
});
?>



There is currently no bulk subscription update functionality in the public API, so a script along the lines of what you've written is the way to achieve this.
While I've not reviewed your code in detail, this approach should work in most cases. Something to keep in mind is API rate limits, and making sure you pace your requests to stay below those limits (allowing room for your normal operations, too) and handle any 429 responses gracefully to retry.
